# Python dual- variable search algorithm

Tags: python, search

I have an algorithm which:

- takes two inputs (x, y), where x and y are the 'lambda' variables in two independent Poisson distributions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Definition)
- calculate Poisson vectors for each of x and y,
- computes the matrix product of the two Poisson vectors
- returns [sum(upper_quadrant), sum(lower_quadrant), sum(diagonal)]

So:

```
import math, random

def poisson(m, n):
    p=math.exp(-m)
    r=[p]
    for i in range(1, n):
        p*=m/float(i)
        r.append(p)
    return r

def simulate(mx, my, n):
    r=[0.0 for i in range(3)]
    px, py = (poisson(mx, n), 
              poisson(my, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i > j:
                k=0
            elif i < j:
                k=1
            else:
                k=2
            r[k]+=px[i]*py[j]
    return r
```

Now I need to solve for x and y, given a particular set of outputs. I have hacked together the following solver function:

```
def solve(p, n, generations, decay, tolerance):
    def rms_error(X, Y):
        return (sum([(x-y)**2 
                     for x, y in zip(X, Y)])/float(len(X)))**0.5
    def calc_error(x, y, n, target):
        guess=simulate(x, y, n)
        return rms_error(target, guess)    
    q=[0, 0]
    err=calc_error(math.exp(q[0]), math.exp(q[1]), n, p)
    bestq, besterr = q, err
    for i in range(generations):
        if besterr < tolerance:
            break
        q=list(bestq)
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            j=0
        else:
            j=1
        fac=((generations-i+1)/float(generations))**decay
        q[j]+=random.gauss(0, 1)*fac
        err=calc_error(math.exp(q[0]), math.exp(q[1]), n, p)
        if err < besterr:
            bestq, besterr = q, err
            # print (i, bestq, besterr)
    q, err = [math.exp(q) for q in bestq], besterr
    return (i, q, err)
```

which works, but seems to take a relatively large number of tries to return a not-very-optimised response:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    p, n = [0.5, 0.2, 0.3], 10
    q, err = solve_match_odds(p, n, 
                              generations=1000,
                              decay=2,
                              tolerance=1e-5)
    print q
    print simulate_match_odds(q[0], q[1], n)
    print (i, err)
```

And:

```
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X220:~/work/$ python solve.py 
[0.5, 0.2, 0.3]
[0.5000246335218251, 0.20006624338256798, 0.29990837191131686]
(999, 6.680993630511076e-05)
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X220:~/work/$
```

I am not a CS major and feel I am missing out on a whole range of search literature here. Could someone suggest a better way to search for variables in a 2-d space such as this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) library to solve this:

```
import math, random

def poisson(m, n):
    p=math.exp(-m)
    r=[p]
    for i in range(1, n):
        p*=m/float(i)
        r.append(p)
    return r

def simulate(mx, my, n):
    r=[0.0 for i in range(3)]
    px, py = (poisson(mx, n), 
              poisson(my, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i > j:
                k=0
            elif i < j:
                k=1
            else:
                k=2
            r[k]+=px[i]*py[j]
    return r

from scipy import optimize

Target, N = [0.5, 0.2, 0.3], 10

def error(p, target, n):
    r = simulate(p[0], p[1], n)
    return np.sum(np.subtract(target, r)**2)

r = optimize.fmin(error, (0, 0), args=(Target, N))
print simulate(r[0], r[1], n)
```

output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 67
         Function evaluations: 125
[0.49999812501285623, 0.20000418001288445, 0.2999969464616799]
```

Comment: Nice, but I should have added that it needs to work on AppEngine https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: You can find a Python source implementation of the Nelder-Mead method used by optimize.fmin() [here](http://www.mech.uq.edu.au/courses/mech2700/python-code/nelmin.py) though I haven't personally tested it.

Comment: I've had a closer look and you would have to modify the code that I linked to slightly to pass your extra arguments `n` and `target` through to the objective function, but that wouldn't be a big deal compared to the benefits of much greater precision for many fewer function evaluations.